# The difference between Laughed and Laughing in my sentence

Tags: adjectives, questions, nouns

I have two phrases but I can't understand what's the difference between them.

> I will make you laughing.

and

> I will make you laughed.

Comment: 'I will make you laughed' does not seem right to me. Your other sentence is ok grammar-wise

Comment: Well, they're both wrong, so the difference is basically irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Make as a causative verb is used in the way **make somebody do something**
So your sentence must be structured as

> I will make you laugh.

Answer (score 0):

"Will make" is the future tense of the word "do".

"Laughing" is present tense.

"Laughed" is past tense.

So, both sentences have problems, because they mix tenses.

If you are going for future tense, then "I will make you laugh."

Present tense: "I'm making you laugh."

Past tense: "I made you laugh."

Comment: I wanna say that, I will make you fun and the people will be laughing of you, do you understand me ?

Comment: This is not at all the reason for them being wrong. (And *laughing* has no tense.) Both sentences are wrong because **make you** needs to be followed by a verb in the infinitive. It has nothing to do with mixing tenses.